# cross compiling error for helloworld program

Tags: compiling, gcc, make, cross-compilation

I have already created the amhello-1.0.tar.gz using this tutorial
[click to open](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Hello-World)

now am trying to make cross compiling but error occurs. i am following this tutorial 
[click to open](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Cross_002dCompilation)

after entering `make` command error occurs

```
hp@ubuntu:~/amhello-1.0$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/hp/amhello-1.0'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/hp/amhello-1.0/src'
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc  -g -O2   -o hello.exe main.o  
main.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [hello.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hp/amhello-1.0/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hp/amhello-1.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are re-using the same build directory for the cross-compile that you used for the original native build. The 'make' program doesn't know that you've changed toolchains, and doesn't consider the object file (main.o) to be out of date - so it doesn't try to recompile it, it just jumps straight to the link step - which fails because it's trying to link a native ELF object with foreign (mingw) libraries.

Try executing a `make clean` or `rm src/*.o` before the `make` to force full recompilation.

Comment: i spent 3 days to figure out how to cross-compile and atlast after lots and lots of searching on google i found a tutorial but then got stuck on this error. thanks alot :)

Comment: i want to ask one more thing . can i do the same procedure for gtk+2 c codes????